# Laravel what relation to use in order to see data from another model and column

Tags: laravel, orm

I have two models

Item:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'code',
    'name',
    'uom'
];


public function recipe()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Recipe');
}
```

Recipe:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'recipecode',
    'itemcode',
    'qty'
];

public function item()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Item');
}
```

In migration I have:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('recipes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('itemcode')->references('code')->on('items');
    });
}
```

In RecipesController I have:

```
public function index()
{
    $recipes = Recipe::all()->sortBy('recipecode');
    $items = Item::all();
    return view ('recipe.index', compact('recipes', 'items'));
}
```

I want to see in the view recipecode, itemcode and ItemName, ItemQty etc.

```
@foreach($recipes as $recipe)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $recipe->recipecode }}</td>  // this works
        <td>{{ $recipe->itemcode }}</td>    // this works
        <td>{{ $recipe->item->name }}</td>  // this doesn't work
        <td>{{ $recipe->item->uom }}</td>   // this doesn't work
        <td>{{ $recipe->item->qty }}</td>   // this doesn't work
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

What should I do in order to see 'name' and 'uom' columns from Items table? I think there is a problem with relations...

Answer (score 0):

First, `$recipe->item->name` does not work as you expected because `$recipe->item` is a collection of `App\Item`, not an `App\Item` model instance. That's because you have set the relationship to be "[hasMany](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)"

Second, please read more about [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading). What you're doing now are multiple queries. That's the N+1, for each recipe you are querying the database to get the items. You do not need to do that, as it's not performant at all. Use `Recipe::with('item')->sortBy('recipecode')->get()`.

Now, keep in mind that `$recipe->item` is not a single item, but a collection of items that belong to that Recipe. You'll probably have to work a bit on your table to display multiple items for one Recipe.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `hasMany` you must follow naming convention in naming function

```
public function items()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Item');
}
```

In RecipesController you can eager load.

```
$recipes = Recipe::with('items')->sortBy('recipecode')->get();
```

Read documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships

Also to show it in your blade

```
 @foreach($recipes as $recipe)
     <tr>
         <td>{{ $recipe->recipecode }}</td>  // this works
         <td>{{ $recipe->itemcode }}</td>    // this works
         @foreach($recipe->items as $item)
             <td>{{ $item->name }}</td> 
         @endforeach
     </tr>
  @endforeach
```

Comment: Is the first line "must" follow or "should" follow?

Comment: @NabilFarhan yes must follow for you to easily identify the use of specific function name

Comment: "Must" generally means that without it the code won't run. For example, you "must" end a statement with semicolon. I think in this particular case, should seems more appropriate.

Comment: Yep also for you to distinguish plural to a singular use also for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers share why you can't directly use `$recipe->item`. However, I think there is a bigger mistake in database design.

The database that you have designed have a one to many relation. Like, one recipe has a lot of items. However, the reverse one that one item has only one recipe seems wrong. You can cook many recipes with one items. I.E. you can make chicken fry and chicken curry with chicken.

The database design should be something like this,

```
recipes: code, name, uom
items: code, name
item_recipe: item_code, recipe_code, qty
```